# Operation speed on different types

Tags: c++, performance

I have quite stupid class task: measure which types works faster in C++. Firstly I thought "it`s obvious, that the fastest type is the type that corresponds to processor word-size, so it will be int64_t on my AMD Ryzen 7 2700x) and, of course, double and float will be much slower than ints. I wrote simple program, but can`t explain its output to myself... Probably, I`m missing something. (compiled in x64 release msvc142).

```
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
T** newMatr1(size_t n)
{
    T** res = new T * [n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        res[i] = new T[n];
    }
    return res;
}
template <typename T>
void delMatr1(T** matr, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[] matr[i];
    }
    delete matr;
}
template <typename T>
void initMatr(T** matr, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            matr[i][j] = rand();
        }   
    }   
}

template <typename T>
void multiplyMatr(T** matr1, T** matr2, size_t n)
{
    T** res = newMatr1<T>(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                res[i][j] += matr1[i][k] * matr2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    delMatr1(res, n);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> initVec(size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> matr(n, std::vector<T>(n));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            matr[i][j] = rand();
        }
    }
    return matr;
}

template <typename T>
void multiplyVect(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& matr1, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& matr2, size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> res(n, std::vector<T>(n));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                res[i][j] += matr1[i][k] * matr2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }   

}

template <typename Func, typename T>
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration getMinTime(Func function, const T& matr1, const T& matr2,  int n, int count)
{
    auto min = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration::max();
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        function(matr1, matr2, n);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto diff = end - start;
        if(diff < min)
            min = diff;
    }
    return min;
}

template <typename T>
void getTime()
{
    std::vector<size_t> sizes{ 512 };// , 1024, 2048
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << sizes[i] << ":\n";
        std::cout << "std::vector: ";
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> vec1 = initVec<T>(sizes[i]);
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> vec2 = initVec<T>(sizes[i]);
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(getMinTime(multiplyVect<T>, vec1, vec2, sizes[i], 10)).count() << "ms";
        std::cout << " arr(raw ptr): ";
        T** matr1 = newMatr1<T>(sizes[i]);
        T** matr2 = newMatr1<T>(sizes[i]);
        initMatr(matr1, sizes[i]);
        initMatr(matr2, sizes[i]);
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(getMinTime(multiplyMatr<T>, matr1, matr2, sizes[i], 10)).count() << "ms\n";
        delMatr1(matr1, sizes[i]);
        delMatr1(matr2, sizes[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> sizes{ 512, 1024 }; //, 2048
    std::cout << "int8_t\n";
    getTime<int8_t>();
    std::cout << "int16_t\n";
    getTime<int16_t>();
    std::cout << "int32\n";
    getTime<int>();
    std::cout << "int64_t\n";
    getTime<int64_t>();
    std::cout << "float\n";
    getTime<float>();
    std::cout << "double\n";
    getTime<double>();
    system("pause");
}
```

the output I got:

int8_t
512:
std::vector: 233ms arr(raw ptr): 228ms
int16_t
512:
std::vector: 233ms arr(raw ptr): 230ms
int32
512:
std::vector: 237ms arr(raw ptr): 235ms
int64_t
512:
std::vector: 250ms arr(raw ptr): 236ms
float
512:
std::vector: 104ms arr(raw ptr): 104ms
double
512:
std::vector: 106ms arr(raw ptr): 106ms

what is wrong? Why floats and doubles are much faster that ints? And why double not slower than float?
Flags:
/permissive- /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\tmp.pch" /diagnostics:column

Comment: did you turn on compiler optimizations? Please post the flags you used to invoke the compiler

Comment: what do you think is wrong about the results? What else did you expect?

Comment: `std::vector<size_t> sizes{ 512 };` creates a vector with a single element - the number 512. So your loop only runs once, making your measurements completely inaccurate

Comment: Actually, your assumption that the word size is the fastest type is generally not accurate. `int` is meant to be the fastest integer type to access on the architecture, and on 64-bit architectures it's usually still 32-bit.

Comment: @UnholySheep i suppose this is intended. OP is making a single measurment with a vector of size `sizes[i]` ie a vector of size `512`. `initVec` initializes a 2d vector of size 512x512

Comment: @UnholySheep If you'd look closely you see that for each size, the measurement is run 10 times.

Comment: btw I remember a talk of one of the gurus where it was discussed in lenght that one should not use average of measurements also not minimum, but the maximum. I still prefer average, but I wouldn't count too much on the minimum.

Comment: I quickly pasted your code into godbolt and compiled it with "/O2 /arch:AVX512". I am by no means an expert in assembler language, but I see a lot of vector (SSE?) instructions e.g. in `multiplyVector<float>` or `double`, but none in `int` instantiation.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Minimum is used to remove the effects of large outliers from context switches in the middle of computation (inflate wall clock time). If processor time was used, maybe use maximum.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ive added flags

Comment: "`int` is the fastest type for that machine" died a death to "`int` is 32 bits" on 64 bit platforms because of all the code that assumed the latter.